# PHP check if string contains maximum 30 letters/numbers in a sequence with preg_match

Tags: php, string, preg-match, match, sequence

I'm stuck here and I can't find any results for my question, maybe because english is not my native language.

I want to match lines which contain maximum 30 letters/numbers in a sequence:

Is this even possible with preg_match?

```
preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9](max 30 in a sequence)/", $string)
```

Strings:

```
$string = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"; // FALSE
$string = "sdfihsgbfsadiousdghiug"; // TRUE
$string = "cfgvsdfsdf786sdf78s9d8g7stdg87stdg78tsd7g0tsd9g7t"; // FALSE
$string = "65656.sdfsdf.sdfsdf"; // TRUE
$string = "ewrwet_t876534875634875687te8---7r9w358wt3587tw3587"; // TRUE
$string = "sd879dtg87dftg87dftg87ftg87tfg087tfgtdf8g7tdf87gt8t___454"; // FALSE
```

Comment: I think you want to add `{0,30}`.

Comment: do you also want to match `-` and `_`? I had the impressions that was only letters and numbers. you say this is true `ewrwet_t876534875634875687te8---7r9w358wt3587tw3587` but I cannot see 30 chars in a sequence.

Comment: -,.: are separators, so if you have string like this "123_abc" there are 2 parts with length = 3 each

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me, In order to help you, please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to find if there's 30 or more of these characters with:

```
preg_match("/[A-Za-z0-9]{30,}/", $string)
```

See matches in bold:

> **1234567890123456789012345678901234567890**
>   sdfihsgbfsadiousdghiug
>   **cfgvsdfsdf786sdf78s9d8g7stdg87stdg78tsd7g0tsd9g7t**
>   65656.sdfsdf.sdfsdf
>   ewrwet_t876534875634875687te8---7r9w358wt3587tw3587
>   **sd879dtg87dftg87dftg87ftg87tfg087tfgtdf8g7tdf87gt8t**___454

http://regexr.com/3arj2

And then negate the result:

```
preg_match("/[A-Za-z0-9]{30,}/", $string) === 0
// returns 0 if no match
// or FALSE if error
```

Comment: i want to match string like this 123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123_123 which has more than 30 characters in total, but each part has max 3 characters

Comment: Try the solution I posted. Replace `30` by the max number of characters in sequence allowed.

Comment: yes you are right, i think this is what i want, tyvm :)

Comment: thanks for adding that regex site, now this answer is exactly what i wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to match alphanumeric strings that are longer than 30 characters, you need to match a non-alphanumeric character at the end and beginning of your expression

```
preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{1,30}[^A-Za-z0-9]/", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Non of your examples will match, your regex is incorrect. You need the `^` outside of the character class, inside it means exclude. If nothing entered is valid this should work. If not change the `0` to a `1`.

```
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]{0,30}/", $string)
```